# Need documents from different collection joined in the same document in MongoDB using aggregation framework with information such as count and detail

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection Called surveys which stores details about surveys like title, image of survey. There's an array of questions in surveys object which stores many questions for that surveys.

```
    {
  "surveyID": 1,
  "title": "survey title",
  "questions": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "title": "first question",
      "choices": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "title": "second question",
      "choices": [
        "D",
        "E",
        "F"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now each survey will get many responses which is stored in a different collection called as Responses. Each response object has

```
    {
  "id": 1,
  "surveyID": 1,
  "responses": [
    {
      "questionID": 1,
      "answer": "A"
    },
    {
      "questionID": 1,
      "answer": "B"
    },
    {
      "questionID": 2,
      "answer": [
        "F",
        "E"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get a document like this

```
{
  "surveyID": 1,
  "totalNumberOfRespones":4,
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionID": 1,
      "choices": [ {"choice":"A", "numberOfResponse":1}, {"choice":"B", "numberOfResponse":1}],
      "title": "first question"
    },
    {
      "questionID": 2,
      "choices": [ {"choice":"F", "numberOfResponse":1}, {"choice":"E", "numberOfResponse":1}],
      "title": "second question"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `questions` array
- `$lookup` with `response` collection pass `surveyID` and `questionID` to lookup pipeline
- `$match` `surveyID` condition
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `responses` and find matching `questionID`'s response
- `$unwind` deconstruct `responses` array
- `$addFields` to check condition if `answer`s field type is not array then convert it to the array because we are going to unwind in next stage
- `$unwind` deconstruct `answer` array
- `$group` by `surveyID`, `questionID` and `answer` choice and get count
- `$group` by `surveyID` and construct the `questions` array and get `totalNumberOfRespones` sum

```
db.survey.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$questions" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "response",
      let: {
        surveyID: "$surveyID",
        questionID: "$questions._id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$surveyID", "$surveyID"] } } },
        {
          $addFields: {
            responses: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$responses",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$this.questionID", "$$questionID"] }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$responses" },
        {
          $addFields: {
            "responses.answer": {
              $cond: [
                { $isArray: "$responses.answer" },
                "$responses.answer",
                ["$responses.answer"]
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$responses.answer" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              surveyID: "$surveyID",
              questions: "$responses.questionID",
              answer: "$responses.answer"
            },
            numberOfResponses: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            choice: "$_id.answer",
            numberOfResponses: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "questions.choices"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$surveyID",
      questions: { $push: "$questions" },
      totalNumberOfRespones: {
        $sum: { $sum: "$questions.choices.numberOfResponses" }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zxFH8p5C3S9)

Comment: Hey @turivishal,thank you for giving the answer but looks like I technically made a mistake in the output document from the query, I actually need to have the choices and number of responses on the choices and not totally for the question

Comment: okay i have updated the answer you can review it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! Can't really thank you enough man. 
I actually posted not the whole problem, what if I want to add totalNumberOfRespones property under survey ID which basically sums up all the number of responses  like in the case above, it will considered as 4. I am trying to do it myself but the group property is not allowing me to do it. 
 Also just one question I have, do you think the architecture of this design is good or would you have kept the responses in the same surveys collection only ?

Comment: i can not say the architecture is good or not, it depends on your project, if there are limited survey questions and answer then you can make it in single collection, if there are lots of questions in survey then make it 2 collection. this query is big it will affect on performance and speed, so for just I would recommend you to increment count in survey collection in choice when some one answer, so no need to do this query,

Comment: Okay thank you for answering. I really appreciate it man. 
Can you also add a number of total responses in this query, I have edited the question as per the final requirement. I am gonna keep this query for later on purpose, for now I am gonna increment the count directly in survey collection. Thank you!

Comment: Hey @turivishal, there is no title of question  in your query, have you missed out the part or is it not possible to do it? Thanks. This only has choicesArray and not questionID and title in questionsArray

Comment: can you confirm again, question title is already there. the _id is questionID

Comment: Hey I am also checking the query, questionID and title are not there and if you mean _id in project then you have kept it as 0 only in project which returns whole object. 
Title is not used anywhere in your query also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233271/discussion-between-prateek-banga-and-turivishal).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full response, but try $lookup with pipeline ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)).

You can start with this, and add $group after:

```
 pipeline =   [{$unwind: {
  path: "$questions"
}}, {$lookup: 
{
  from: 'a',
  let: {sid: '$surveyID',qid: "$questions._id"},
  pipeline: [{$unwind: {path: "$responses"}},{ $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$surveyID",  "$$sid" ] },
                         { $eq: [ "$responses.questionID", "$$qid" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }],
  as: 'questions'
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: '$questions',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
}}]
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```